# YouTube:- The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

After successfully uploading 9-10 videos, we encountered the following error, even though each video's size is below 30 MB, and our OAuth App's limit has not been reached. The average total uploaded video size, well within our 300 MB limit, is spread across these uploads. The total video duration for the batch of uploads is only 20-30 minutes. Therefore, it appears that this error message is incorrect or does not align with our usage.

> Error Message:
> {
> "error": {
> "code": 400,
> "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.",
> "errors": [
> {
> "message": "The user has exceeded the number of videos they may upload.",
> "domain": "youtube.video",
> "reason": "uploadLimitExceeded"
> }
> ]
> }
> }

We kindly request assistance in resolving this issue as it seems to be occurring erroneously and does not match our usage patterns where we are well within the OAuth App's limit.

Thank you for your help in addressing this matter.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a limited number of videos you can upload via the API per day no matter what your quota may be.  This does not effect the number of videos you can upload though Googles YouTube Web application.  This limit is strictly for API usage.

Last I knew the number was twenty but it has changed several times in the past. When I started it was around fifty. You should wait until tomorrow and try again.

You can find the documentation for this error message here [videos_youtube.videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#videos_youtube.videos.insert)